# making a script so it types something

Tags: programmers-notepad

I am getting started with so keep in mind that I don't know much.
I just want a script that could type something where I put my cursor and then I would press a hotkey so that it would start typing.
i don't care what the hotkey is.

Answer (score 0):

It's called copy and paste.

The hotkeys are Ctrl-C (or X to cut) and Ctrl-V.